# PHP preg_replace() pattern to find img with certain folder

Tags: regex, wordpress

I am trying to replace broken images from the blog post- the_content() with a placeholder. Two folders from my media folder are missing and this is causing the broken images.

So following suggestion would work for me, i felt

```
<?php 
$content = get_the_content();
$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "placeholderim", $content);          
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content); echo $content; ?>
```

But I want to match the pattern with image and the image URL should contain 2017 || 2018. How to create this pattern. Any help please!

Comment: Please provide example input and example output.

Comment: https://www.website.ca/wp-content/uploads/2019/myimg.jpg
https://www.website.ca/wp-content/uploads/2018/myimg.jpg

i want to filter out the image from the blog post with the folder 2019 & 2018

preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "placeholderim", $content). This will replace any image from the blog post but I want to filter image with folders 2019 & 2018
@JM-AGMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finds all html image tags that has 2019 or 2020 anywhere in it.

```regex
/(<img[^>]+(2019|2020)+[^>]+>)/ig
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/0rdwd2/1

For PHP (untested) this would be:

```php
$content = get_the_content();
$content = preg_replace("/(<img[^>]+(2019|2020)+[^>]+>)/ig", "placeholderim", $content);
```